# Problem with importing MIDI file created in FL Studio 20.8.4 to Ableton Live 11 Lite

Tags: ableton-live, fl-studio

I want to import to Ableton Live Lite chords I've created in FL Studio by exporting them as midi and importing them into Ableton Live. When I try to import a sample midi file found in internet into Ableton Live, I have no problem, but when I try to import by dragging (just like I did with the sample which worked) a midi file created/exported from FL Studio, Ableton Live shows me the forbidden icon, like it can't be dragged or moved there. Why can this be? Is there anything I can do to move the chords from FL Studio to Ableton Live and not having to rewrite them manually all of them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because it's off topic. Sorry but your question is more related to software and UI aspects, than actual music practice and/or theory (even indirectly). Also, drag&drop aspects may change depending on program or OS versions and capabilities, so we really can't help you with that here, as your problem has nothing to do with subjects normally discussed on this website. Consider asking your question to an Ableton Live related site, help-desk or forum.